# Dijkstra's Algorithm - two solutions possible?

Tags: algorithms

I did a homework question, which was choosing the shortest path to the other points from a point using Dijkstra's Algorithm.

I ended up with the following, whilst an online applet resulted in something else (upper graph is my try, lower one is the applet's one):
[image: graphs]

(The vertices in the second image have different names, but I tried to use the same shape of the graph.)

So, instead of B-D I did E-D. For D, the routes B-D and B-E-D are of equal length, so I was wondering whether both are indeed correct.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to the shortest path problem is not unique.

Imagine you have a 2-node graph, let's call the nodes A and B. You have, say, 10 edges between them, all of equal weight w. Then the shortest path from A to B is any one of these 10 edges, so the solution is not unique. In particular, it depends on the order in which you traverse the nodes in each iteration.

Comment: I see, thanks. So am I right in thinking that both solutions are correct?

Comment: If you get the same length as the other solution probably yes.

Comment: Note that this answer is true also for simple graphs; consider $K_n$ with $w(e) = c$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$.